# How to combine similar functions - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two functions that are very similar and I would like if possible to combine them. The only issue that I have is one function is accepting 2 arguments and the other one is accepting 3. Is there a way to do this or these two functions have to stay separated by design?

```
function getClientData(id, command) {

    var formData = {
        'method': command,
        'id': id
    };

    getEntityData(formData);
}


function getLocation(id, clientid, command) {

    var formData = {
        'method': command,
        'locationid': id,
        'clientbrandid': clientid
    };

    getEntityData(formData);
}
```

**Update**

```
function getEntityData(data) {

    var url = '/../admin/miscellaneous/components/global.cfc?wsdl';

    var ajaxResponse = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        global: false,
        async:false,
        cache: false,
        success: function(apiResponse){
            return apiResponse;
        }
    }).responseJSON;

    var response = ajaxResponse[0];

    for (var i in response) {
        if (response.hasOwnProperty(i)){
            $("#edit"+i).val(response[i].trim());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Really you have 4 parameters as *id* and *locationid* are passed to *getEntityData* with different names. Are they the same thing? You haven't shown what *getEntityData* does.

Comment: I will update now. The getEntityData is just an ajax function which takes the data in the `data:` section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you can, I prefer instead of passing each parameter you can pass a js object, and decide wich params it contains for example:

```
function getLocation(options) {

    getEntityData(options);
}
```

and your call should be:

```
getLocation({'method': command,'id': id})
```

**Update**

or you can just avoid getLocation function and just call getEntityData

```
getEntityData({
    'method': command,
    'id': id
});
```

Comment: this looks awesome. Will try it and let you know!!

Comment: At this point, having the `getLocation` function is useless, isn't it? He could just call `getEntityData` directly.

Comment: That is what i was thinking as well @ColinDeClue. Thanks for the update :)

Answer (score 3):

```
function getLocation(id, clientid, command) {
    var formData = {
        'method': command,
        'locationid': id
    };

    if (clientid) {
        formData['clientbrandid'] = clientid;
    }

    getEntityData(formData);
}

// With
getLocation(1, 2, 'doStuff');

// Without
getLocation(1, '', 'doStuff');
```

Maybe a more rational order of arguments:

```
function getLocation(id, command, clientid) {
    var formData = {
        'method': command,
        'locationid': id
    };

    if (clientid) {
        formData['clientbrandid'] = clientid;
    }

    getEntityData(formData);
}

// With
getLocation(1, 'doStuff', 2);

// Without
getLocation(1, 'doStuff');
```

And if `locationid` and `id` are different:

```
function getLocation(id, command, clientid) {
    if (clientid) {
        var formData = {
            'method': command,
            'locationid': id,
            'clientbrandid': clientid
        };
    } else {
        var formData = {
            'method': command,
            'id': id,
        };
    }

    getEntityData(formData);
}

// With
getLocation(1, 'doStuff', 2);

// Without
getLocation(1, 'doStuff');
```

Comment: just be aware that if you are doing this in an existing codebase that actively uses these to function that the function signature (order of arguments is different). you will need to refactor your existing code.

Comment: Might be better to make the optional argument last so it doesn't need to be elided.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it really depends on what your arguments actually are, but this is also a solution.  (Assuming that client id is an object).

```
function getLocation(id, command, clientid) {

    var _clientId = clientid || {};

    var formData = {
        'method': command,
        'locationid': id,
        'clientbrandid': _clientid
    };

    getEntityData(formData);
}
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `'clientbrandid': _clientid`? Otherwise it's just an unused variable, correct?

Answer (score 3):

I would go with:

```
function getWhatever(id, command, clientId) {
    var formData = { method: command };

    if (typeof clientId === 'undefined') {
        formData.id = id;
    } else {
        formData.locationid = id;
        formData.clientbrandid = clientId;
    }

    getEntityData(formData);
}
```